# Video source wont change from default

Tags: html, caching, html5-video

I'm making a little video site and using react-html5video to show video in react. This works fine and I had a video called "testvid.mp4" which worked perfectly. I wanted to make a second video page for representation reasons. So I changed the video "testvid.mp4" to "makeupvid.mp4" and also added another video called "bikinivid.mp4". When I try to play any of these videos it says file not found. However when I type "http://localhost:8080/media/video/testvid.mp4" in the url it returns the old video! This video doesn't exist anymore yet its the only one that is working. I've cleared chrome cache, restarted servers and restarted workstation to no avail.

The file paths are correct for the videos naming.

The video tag

```
 <Video loop='loop' controls={['PlayPause', 'Seek', 'Time', 'Volume', 
 'Fullscreen']} poster={userData.thumbnail}>
     <source src='../../../media/video/testvid.mp4' type='video/mp4'/>
  </Video>
```

So this works perfectly even if the testvid.mp4 file doesn't exist and no matter how many times I clear my cache and restart it wont go away.

[image]

Is this some sort of weird caching problem or am I doing something stupid?

Comment: You sure the path is right? Looks like it should be `/src/media/video/` (missing `src`). I like starting at the root (`/`) and working down instead of backwards (`../../../`). I don't know why testvid would still play.

Comment: Yes and I've since fixed the problem but I had to make a new directory and make new copies of the videos everything was perfect I have absolutely no idea what was happening. I can still play the video that doesn't exist a day later! So I'm guessing its not a cache issue. It makes zero sense in the directory the term "testvid" isn't even in the codebase anymore yet it works.